# How can I execute a command from command line in back ground

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I have written vb script to run jar command from windows command line in foreground

```
'File paths
 processFile = "java -jar doSomething.jar C:\folder1\subFolder1 C:\folder2\subFolder2"      

 Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

 objShell .run "cmd /k CD C:\VBScriptfolder\script" 'Path to vbscript which contains command to run from command line
 WScript.Sleep 5000 
 Wait(5)
 objShell .SendKeys processFile 
 WScript.Sleep 3000 
 Wait(3)
 objShell .SendKeys "{ENTER}"
 WScript.Sleep 40000 
 Wait(60)
 objShell .SendKeys "exit{ENTER}"
```

But my question is that how to run above command from command line which execute the command in background instead of foreground.

Comment: What do you mean by "background"? Asynchronously? Hidden? Or both? Or something else?

Comment: Bond, I meant hidden

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `SendKeys()` on a hidden window. It must be visible and active. I posted a hack to overcome this a while ago but it's definitely a hack. It involves changing the opening position of the command prompt window, which is stored in the registry, so that it's created offscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your command line and debug it with **wscript.echo**.
And, if you feel that it is correct , you should comment the **wscript.echo** and uncomment this line **Call Run(StrCmd,0,False) 'Hiding the console**

```
Option Explicit
Dim StrCmd,Path,processFile
Path = "C:\VBScriptfolder\script" 'Path to vbscript which contains command to run from command line
processFile = "java -jar doSomething.jar C:\folder1\subFolder1 C:\folder2\subFolder2"
StrCmd = "CD /D "& Path & " & " & processFile &""
wscript.echo StrCmd
'Call Run(StrCmd,1,False) 'Showing the console
'Call Run(StrCmd,0,False) 'Hiding the console
'**********************************************************************************************
Function Run(StrCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Result
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'A value of 0 to hide the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
'A value of 1 to show the MS-DOS console
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & ""
        Result = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,bWaitOnReturn)
        If Result = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "An unknown error has occurred!",16,"An unknown error has occurred!"
        End If
    End If
    Run = Result
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: This will surely hide the command prompt window but I think OP wants to be able to send keystrokes to it.

Comment: I ran above code i got error in command prompt             The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Did you mean you run it as it is posted like that and you don't change anything to your settings ?